# Django 'datetime.datetime' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I just want to update my model:

My view:

```
message = InboxRecruiting.objects.get(id=id_message, on_team=team, is_removed=False)

message.update(is_read_team=True)
```

My model:

```
class InboxRecruiting(models.Model):
    on_team = models.ForeignKey(Team, verbose_name="Equipe")
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="De", related_name='from_user')
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Vers", related_name='to_user')
    is_read_team = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Lu (auteur)")
    is_read_player = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Lu (destinataire)")
    is_removed = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Supprimé")
    is_accepted = models.NullBooleanField(default=None, verbose_name="Accepté")
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, verbose_name="Date de création")
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Dernière modification")

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)
```

It returns an error: `'datetime.datetime' object is not callable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`update` is a field on the model.

That's not how you update instances, anyway. You need to set the new value and save:

```
message.is_read_team=True
message.save()
```

Alternatively, you can use update on a *queryset*:

```
InboxRecruiting.objects.filter(id=id_message, on_team=team, is_removed=False).update(is_read_team=True)
```